# Node.js How to use a variable in a function globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, global-variables

I have the below function, which reads text from a file and outputs the text into the data variable.

```js
fs.readFile('a1.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {  

   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(data);
});
```

I want to assign data to a global variable so i can use it in other parts of my program. at the moment I am unable to use the information taken from data. What can I do to store data into another variable which i can use freely in other functions?

Comment: It's easy to assign it to a global variable, use `someGlobalVar = data`. But that's different from *consuming* the data asynchronously, which *can't* be done on the global level - you'll have to wrap the whole thing in an async function or use `.then` or a callback.

Comment: Since you are targeting a CommonJS environment, attaching a property to `module.exports` makes a lot more sense than an actual global. That said, it doesn't sound like your really want a variable as much as that you don't understand how callbacks work. Take a look at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is not really global, just a higher scope than the function.

Seeing as you're in node.js, you can just put a variable at the top of your file (or wherever):

```
var a1Data;
```

then just use `a1Data = data` in the callback.

If you truly want something global, you can use `global.whatever = data`, but that's typically not what you want.

Comment: not to mention that `readFile` is asynchronous so using the global variable after the call might stuff up the rest of the application.

Comment: Yes and no; just because something is asynchronous doesn't mean you can't guarantee that you're only using it when it's initialized correctly.

Comment: Will I be able to use a1Data in other functions?

Comment: When I try that, it gives me an undefined message.

Comment: @DelsE Yes, because that's global. I would need to see more code to debug what you're doing to cause the undefined issue though.